# ASP.NET Microsoft OWIN Token becomes invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, owin

I used OWIN to support oauth2.0 and it worked perfectly, but after few hours the token becomes invalid for some reason.

1. Authenticate to get the token
2. Send the token in each request ( Authorization: Bearer `token` )
3. It first work perfectly, then after few hours it becomes invalid with this error ( in OWIN trace )

   `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthBearerAuthenticationMiddleware Warning: 0 : invalid bearer token received`

So basically the client receives error 401.
This was tested using different clients types ( mobile app/postman/fiddler )

**Startup.cs**

```
var options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/path/to/token"),
    Provider = new AppOAuthProvider(),
    RefreshTokenProvider = new RefreshTokenProvider(),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true,
};

app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(options);
```

**AppOAuthProvider.cs**

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
{
    // Initialization.  
    string usernameVal = context.UserName;
    string passwordVal = context.Password;

    User User = authenticate();

    if (User == null )
    {
        context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Invalid user/password");

        context.Response.Headers.Add(OwinChallengeFlag, new[] { ((int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized).ToString() }); //Little trick to get this to throw 401, refer to AuthenticationMiddleware for more
        return;
    }

    /*
        Set permissions/claims
        Permissions are set here
    */

    // Setting Claim Identities for OAUTH 2 protocol.  
    ClaimsIdentity oAuthClaimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    ClaimsIdentity cookiesClaimIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    
    // Setting user authentication.  
    AuthenticationProperties properties = CreateProperties(usernameVal, User, Permissions);
    AuthenticationTicket ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(oAuthClaimIdentity, properties);

    // Grant access to authorize user.  
    context.Validated(ticket);
    context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(cookiesClaimIdentity);
}
```

Note that service is running on shared hosting.

Answer (score 1):

The issue caused from shared hosting; each time IIS is restarted a new machine key is generated, the access token is generated based on the machine key, and so the token fails to authenticate after x time, where x is the restart time for the asp.net or IIS ( depends on the hosting provider ).
To fix this issue, generate a machine key and put it inside `web.config` as follows:

```
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    <machineKey validation="SHA1" decryption="AES" validationKey="yyyysecret" decryptionKey="xxxxsecrect" />
  </system.web>
```

You can generate an machine key using an online tool if you want.